# Syncing an iPad to my desktop iMac

Tags: ipad

I have an iPad which I would like to sync with my desktop Mac.  I don't know where I should go to see the icon which shows the iPad is connected.  (It used to be easy; I could look on the finder and see it, but now the iPad doesn't show up in the Finder at all.)

For my old iPod, it was visible in iTunes, but this iPad is not visible anywhere that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

It should show up in the latest version of iTunes like so:

[image]

OK, that's an iPhone, but my iPad is all the way downstairs.